# Altium: Can one add scripted function into active bar?

Tags: altium

Altium contains Active Bar. It appears in the canvas on the top. It provides a short-cut way to access specific tools. We can add things into it and remove things from it. Items that we find in other menus e.g Tools menu, can be added into the active bar.

My question is, can one add something into the active bar that executes a script or sequence of actions instead?

Comment: Look I am trying to learn Altium so I can use it at job later. Please forgive me for asking questions on this place. My ancestors and all descendants till day of judgement say sorry to you. I use the Altium forum when I can using my work account but its not possible all the time. I know about the Altium forum.

Comment: Here is a blog that may help: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Altium_Designer_Step_by_Step_Guide_on_PCB_Board_Design_890f88b1.html   You can also ask your question to the pcbway forum. There are many altium users.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com/ (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 3):

To have a script run from a toolbar, you must first create a command from the script. There is [good documentation on this](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/running-scripts). The following statement summarizes this process well:

Under **Executing Scripts**:

> The ideal way to access a script's functionality however, is where it is integrated into Altium Designer's GUI as a menu or toolbar command. This is normally a two-step process; implementing a script as a Command (with optional shortcut), then assigning the Command to a Menu (static or pop-up) or a Toolbar.

Be sure to read **Script as a Command** and **Create a Command** for details on getting from script to command.

Further down the page, the section **Assigning Menu Commands** gives you the steps to add the command to a toolbar:

> To assign a custom command to the PCB editor's main menu or Toolbar menu for example, open the Customizing PCB Editor dialog, locate the custom command and drag it to the desired menu location.

Once you've created a custom command, don't forget that you can assign a keyboard shortcut, which in my opinion would be a further improvement so that a button click is not necessary.